# How to put an actual variable n in printf("%nd",var) instead of any integer in C?

Tags: printf

I'm using %nd in a loop where 'var' increments. Now i want 'n' to be the no. of digits of 'var' so that it aligns correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a variable as the width parameter in `printf`using the `*` width specifier:

```
printf("%*d\n", digs, var);
```

This will use the value of the `digs` variable as the format width.

A simple, complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
        printf("%*d\n", i, i); // i is used both as the width specifier and the actual value printed!
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. This is exactly what i wanted. Now i just need to calculate no. Of digits in no.

Comment: Actually, if you just use a plain `"%d"` then the number of digits will *automatically* be the width of the output! So, `123` will print with a width of 3 and `543210` will print with a width of 6. It's a bit trickier with non-integral types, though, and that's where the `*` specifier gets really powerful.

Comment: Yeah. I wanted that width to be the digits of max no. I wanted it to be constant width for all digit no.s. so i made printf ("%*d",(int)(n*0.3010+1),i);

Comment: Well, if `n` is your "max no." then you should use `printf("%*d", int(log10(n)), i)`. Not sure why you're multiplying by log10(2)?

Comment: n is the power of 2. 2^n is max no. and 0.3010 is log2. I'm generating binary no.s of n bits where output will be saved in a 2d array.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it by generating the desired format-string using `sprintf()` at run-time, like this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(int, char **)
 {
    char formatBuf[100];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
       // Note:  %% specifies one literal %
       //        %d specifies the width-number to put in the format string
       //        ... and the final d is a literal 'd' to include in the format string
       sprintf(formatBuf, "num=%%%dd", i);
       printf("formatBuf=[%s]\n", formatBuf);
       printf(formatBuf, i);
       printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

... which gives this output as a demonstration:

```
 formatBuf=[num=%0d]
 num=0
 formatBuf=[num=%1d]
 num=1
 formatBuf=[num=%2d]
 num= 2
 formatBuf=[num=%3d]
 num=  3
 formatBuf=[num=%4d]
 num=   4
 formatBuf=[num=%5d]
 num=    5
 formatBuf=[num=%6d]
 num=     6
 formatBuf=[num=%7d]
 num=      7
 formatBuf=[num=%8d]
 num=       8
 formatBuf=[num=%9d]
 num=        9
```